# sitemap index and then remove from webmaster

Tags: wordpress, sitemap, google-search-console

when i create sitemap on my website: [webmoney724.ir](http://webmoney724.ir)

webmaster can not index them, on index and after 1 day all of the indexed files removed. i build my sitemap by Yoast SEO plugin. so i don't think this can happen because of sitemap errors.

i think this happen because of crawling problems or site speedو based on Gt-matrix my website is good. google support recommend these:
1- Update your sitemaps: 
2- Keep redirects clean and short. 
3- Make sure deep links to your Android Apps are properly configured.
how can i made changes to number 2? my redirects are long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see your sitemap is already working fine just you need to upload it manually.

You Can Manually Submit your Sitemap in Google Webmaster.

Here we go with the Steps.

**Login into Webmaster -> www.google.com/webmasters/ -> Crawl -> Sitemaps -> ADD/Test Sitemap -> Submit Sitemap URL -> sitemap.xml**

Here is a screen shot for the same.

[image]

Comment: afetr i add it to the webmaster , it show me 404 error.

Comment: Please Check the link of the Sitemap, Only you have to add sitemap link not the overall URL.  For Ex : You if your website sitemap link is http://webmoney724.ir/sitemap_index.xml  then you have to only add sitemap_index.xml not http://webmoney724.ir/sitemap_index.xml

Comment: Hi, @webmoney724 is the above code or step is working. Please let me know.

Comment: the real problem was from using Total cache plugin and Yoast SEO plugin. i found a solution in youast website, that i should refresh one page. it works pretty good and problem is solved. thanks man.

Comment: @webmoney724 : It means my answer is Correct and you have accept it. Thanks